# how to get detail of payment on using 'stripe payment'?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using **stripe** for  payment using php. I have a system like subscription payment where client are made to be paid every month. After implementing subscription payment i am confused that how will i know the subscribed amount or that re-billed amount is added in my stripe account? Don't **stripe** has such mechanism  to post rebill info in my server after it is deducted from the card?
For normal payment i used following code to retrieve payment info, but again its showing error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<?php 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">Stripe.setPublishableKey("' . STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY . '");</script>';
require_once('lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);
Stripe_BalanceTransaction::retrieve("card_14ZJGLIv1**********");
?>
```

And my last question is, in my **stripe** account i can see 'name' field which is empty but when i add input with 'name' it is showing error. How to set that name field. Stripe provide only following code for payment which doesn't include card holder name:

```
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                "amount" => 5000, // amount in cents
                "currency" => "usd",
                "card" => $token,
                "description" => $desc
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### Retrieving a customer's subscription
>
> By default, you can see the 10 most recent active subscriptions stored
> on a customer directly on the customer object, but you can also
> retrieve details about a specific active subscription for a customer.
>
> #### Arguments
>
> **id**: required ID of subscription to retrieve.
>
> **customer**: required
>
> #### Returns
>
> Returns the subscription object.  [That includes amount]

Via [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#retrieve_subscription)

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve({CUSTOMER_ID});   
$subscription = $customer->subscriptions->retrieve({SUBSCRIPTION_ID}));
```

Comment: I would like to add also, Balance Method API is experimental the following is the url you can refer, https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#balance